# Optimization method selection & dealing with convergence and variability

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

### The Problem

I am looking to tackle a minimization problem using `scipy`'s optimization utilities.

Specifically, I've been using this function:

```py
result = spo.minimize(s21_mag, goto_start, options={"disp": True}, bounds=bnds)
```

My `s21_mag` function takes a couple of seconds to return an output (due to physically moving motors). It consists of **3 parameters** (3 moving parts), with no constraints - just three bounds (identical for all 3 parameters):

```py
bnds = ((0,45000),(0,45000),(0,45000))
```

The limit on the amount of iterations is not very constraint (`1000` is probably a good enough upper limit for me), but I expect the optimizer to try many configurations in this set of iterations to identify an optimal value. So far, some methods I've tried just seem to converge somewhere with meaningless progress.

Here's progress beyond the 50th iteration (full code [here](https://github.com/0xCoto/NetworkOptimizer/blob/main/optimize_network.py)) - the goal is the maximization of S21 at a specific frequency (purple vertical line):
[image: progress]

This is with no method passed to`spo.minimize()`, so it uses the default (and it looks like it applies the exact same movement to each motor).

---

### Questions

1. Although `scipy`'s `minimization` function offers a wide variety of optimization methods/algorithms, how could I (as a beginner in optimization math) select the one that would work best for my application? **What kind of aspects of my problem should I take into account to jump to such conclusions?** Assume I have no idea about the initial value of each parameter and want the optimizer to figure that out (I usually just set it to the midpoint, i.e. `initial: x1=x2=x3=22500`).
2. The same set of parameters as an input to my `s21_mag` function could yield different results at different times the function is called.

This happens for two reasons:

- **(a)** The parameter step of the optimizer can get extremely small (particularly as the number of iterations increase and the convergence is approached), whereas the motor expects a minimum value of ~100 to make a step.
- - **Is there a way to somehow set a minimum step?** Otherwise, it tries to step from e.g. `1234.0` to `1234.0001` and eventually gets "stuck" between trying tiny changes.
- **(b)** The output of the function goes through a measuring instrument, which exhibits a little bit of noise (e.g. one measurement may yield `5.42 dB`, while another measurement (with the exact same parameters) may yield `5.43 dB`).
- - **Is there a way to deal with these kinds of small variabilities/errors to avoid confusions for the optimizer?**

Comment: Honestly, without a minimal reproducible example or at least more information about your function `s21_mag`, it's hard to help properly. In the meantime, it's always a good idea to provide exact derivatives, assuming your objective function is differentiable.

Comment: @joni I've attached the full code (the function is defined on line 97). I've also attached a screenshot with progress of the optimizer.

In case it's helpful, here's the detailed log: https://pastebin.com/raw/pJ28zysW (as you can see, it converges in the end to decimal values which I convert to integers since that's what the motors expect).